# Using Apache to Proxy HTTP Requests to HTTPS for Legacy Win32 EXE without SSL Support

Tags: apache, http, https, proxy, cgi

I have a Win32 exe program installed on hundreds of clients. This application makes an HTTP API call to retrieve information about an address based on the provided ZIP code. The exe calls an address like `http://mycepapi.com/?cep=04513010`, where `04513010` is the variable parameter, and receives an XML response with the following information:

```
<result cep="04513010" state="SP" city="São Paulo" neighborhood="Vila Nova Conceição" street="Rua Doutor Ernani Pereira" service="correios-alt"/>
```

Everything works perfectly, except that the server hosting this service has blocked HTTP calls, requiring them to be made using HTTPS. However, the x32 exe does not have SSL enabled, and I cannot update it to use HTTPS.

I have an Apache/2.2.25 (Win32) server running at each of these hundreds of locations, and I would like to know if it's possible to, for example, make a call to `http://192.168.1.10/cep/?cep=04513010`, and have Apache make the request to `https://mycepapi.com/?cep=01431010` and return the generated XML.

Is it possible to achieve this with Apache in this version?

Any ideas on how I could do this with Apache?

---

As a last resort, I'm considering creating a CGI in a more modern language that could receive a request from Apache, perform the HTTPS query to the server, and return the values as received. However, I would like to know if Apache alone could potentially solve my problem. I appreciate any ideas or assistance in advance!

Comment: The API server that now requires HTTPS is not operated by you? I am sure you can use Apache or another server like nginx as http zomhttps bridge, but be aware that this may cause legal problems depending on the license the zip data is published under.

Comment: The server is google, my service is hosted there... I don't think I can convince them to accept http requests